# Why is my Component not calling its init method?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have a UIComponent which has a dependency of a faceless Component.

Main component metadata:

```
jQuery.sap.declare("MYAPP.Component");

sap.ui.core.UIComponent.extend("MYAPP.Component", {
  metadata: {
    dependencies: {
      libs: [],
      components: [
        "MYAPP.Component2"
      ]
    }, etc
```

The app indicates it has reached the faceless component, since if I make some deliberate syntax errors I do get the error messages when loading the webpage. I can also get a console.log("test") to print out from outside the sap.ui.core.Component.extend() code.

```
jQuery.sap.declare("Component2.Component");

console.log("outside test"); //this prints

sap.ui.core.Component.extend("Component2.Component", {
  metadata: {
  },

  init: function(){
    sap.ui.core.Component.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);
    console.log("component2 init test"); //this doesn't print
  }

});
```

Perhaps there's an issue with my declarations of resources?
Some of index.html:

```
<script id='sap-ui-bootstrap' type='text/javascript'
    src='resources/sap-ui-core.js'
    data-sap-ui-theme='sap_bluecrystal'
    data-sap-ui-libs='sap.m, sap.me'
    data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex"
    data-sap-ui-xx-supportedLanguages="en"
    data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{"MYAPP":"./"}'></script>

<script>
  sap.ui.localResources("view");
  sap.ui.localResources("utils");
  sap.ui.localResources("control");
  sap.ui.localResources("Component2");
```

My folder structure:

```
MYAPP
  /Component2               //faceless component folder
    Component.js
  /view                     //views and controllers folder
  Component.js              //main component
  index.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer I've found with some help from a user at SCN ([here](http://scn.sap.com/message/15894962)) is that the parent component's metadata will call a function to load the new component without instantiating it. So you must explicitly create the component as well.

I have added a simple sap.ui.component in the init() function of my parent component.

```
sap.ui.component({ name: "MYAPP.Component2" });
```

Now the new component is loaded and instantiated before the parent component. Hopefully this post will help others using faceless components, as I found little documentation myself when researching this problem.